# Can't test with rspec and elasticsearch-extensions on Ubuntu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, elasticsearch, rspec, elasticsearch-ruby

I've followed [this guide](https://medium.com/@rowanoulton/testing-elasticsearch-in-rails-22a3296d989#.a2sgakhwl) to run integration tests in rspec with the `elasticsearch-extensions` gem, but at the moment I run `Elasticsearch::Extensions::Test::Cluster.start(port: 9250, nodes: 1, timeout: 120)`, the following error is thrown:

```
Starting 2 Elasticsearch nodes...Exception in thread "main" ElasticsearchException[Failed to load logging configuration]; nested: NoSuchFileException[/usr/share/elasticsearch/config];
Likely root cause: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /usr/share/elasticsearch/config
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:86)
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102)
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107)
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileAttributeViews$Basic.readAttributes(UnixFileAttributeViews.java:55)
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.readAttributes(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:144)
        at sun.nio.fs.LinuxFileSystemProvider.readAttributes(LinuxFileSystemProvider.java:99)
        at java.nio.file.Files.readAttributes(Files.java:1737)
        at java.nio.file.FileTreeWalker.getAttributes(FileTreeWalker.java:225)
        at java.nio.file.FileTreeWalker.visit(FileTreeWalker.java:276)
        at java.nio.file.FileTreeWalker.walk(FileTreeWalker.java:322)
        at java.nio.file.Files.walkFileTree(Files.java:2662)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.logging.log4j.LogConfigurator.resolveConfig(LogConfigurator.java:142)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.logging.log4j.LogConfigurator.configure(LogConfigurator.java:103)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:259)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:35)
Refer to the log for complete error details.
Exception in thread "main" ElasticsearchException[Failed to load logging configuration]; nested: NoSuchFileException[/usr/share/elasticsearch/config];
Likely root cause: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /usr/share/elasticsearch/config
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:86)
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102)
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107)
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileAttributeViews$Basic.readAttributes(UnixFileAttributeViews.java:55)
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.readAttributes(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:144)
        at sun.nio.fs.LinuxFileSystemProvider.readAttributes(LinuxFileSystemProvider.java:99)
        at java.nio.file.Files.readAttributes(Files.java:1737)
        at java.nio.file.FileTreeWalker.getAttributes(FileTreeWalker.java:225)
        at java.nio.file.FileTreeWalker.visit(FileTreeWalker.java:276)
        at java.nio.file.FileTreeWalker.walk(FileTreeWalker.java:322)
        at java.nio.file.Files.walkFileTree(Files.java:2662)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.logging.log4j.LogConfigurator.resolveConfig(LogConfigurator.java:142)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.logging.log4j.LogConfigurator.configure(LogConfigurator.java:103)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:259)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:35)
Refer to the log for complete error details.
```

I guess is because I have installed ES in my Ubuntu machine, which adds the config files into `/etc/elasticsearch/` and also is already running as a service. I tried to symlink the folder, but the folder permissions are:

```
drwxr-x---  3 root elasticsearch 4,0K nov  8 17:32 elasticsearch
```

So I tried to add my user to `elasticsearch` group but I had no luck. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I finished just copying the files and changing the owner:

```
sudo cp -r /etc/elasticsearch/ /usr/share/elasticsearch/config
sudo chown $(whoami):$(whoami) /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/*
```

Maybe not the best solution, but effective.